# conditional statement not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am rendering the following using react...

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            register: false
        }
     }
 handleClick(event)
 {
      this.setState({register: true});
 }

    render(){

        //console.log(this.props.exists);

        if (this.state.register || this.props.exists == true) {
            return (
            <Register />
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
            <Index event={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
            );
        }   
    }
}

module.exports = App;
```

So I am using node.js to render the page. When I render as so...

```
var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({exists: false}));
res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
```

`<Index />` gets rendered, as expected and `console.log(this.props.exists)` prints out `false`, also as expected.

However, the problem occurs when I render the page as so...

```
var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({exists: true}));
res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
```

`console.log(this.props.exists)` prints `true`, which is correct. However, the `<Index />` page is getting rendered as opposed to the `<Register />` page.

I suspect it has something to do with

```
( this.state.register || this.props.exists == true )
```

For some reason `this.state.register` is read properly, but `this.props.exists` is never reached.

Can someone show me why this is so?

Comment: Don't set state directly. Use [`getInitialState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getinitialstate) instead.

Comment: `this.props.exists === undefined` that's why first one passes correctly and second one fails

Comment: @IslamIbakaev thats whats strange, it is not undefined, see the console.log in the code above, it prints out true

Comment: @IslamIbakaev oh nvm you're right, it prints `true` but is undefined, can you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `reactDom.renderToString(<App exists={true} />)` not `reactDom.renderToString(App({exists: true}));`

Comment: This didnt fix the issue

Comment: I see you use server side rendering with react, just make sure your browser code don't reload the component.